# What should i do if i can't upgrade ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 lts, but it always went wrong. How could i do it right?

Comment: Please add more information to your question on what went wrong.

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try performing these steps and if they report errors tell us about them by editing your question. (There might be no errors; this might just work to upgrade your system.)

- Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `update-manager -d`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- When the Update Manager comes up, click the Upgrade button.